# How to use the Android P transition animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions, android-9.0-pie

I see plenty of apps animating the transition between views as is done in e.g. the Android P settings app. How do we do that?

Here's a video showing what I mean: https://youtu.be/FvrV0LBrau8

Comment: If you google "Activity Transitions" you'll find plenty of resources, even official. Start there. Also, go to developer settings and slow down transition animation speed. That will help you understnad better what the animation does.

Comment: This particular transition does not even work with views across activities so it should be fairly simple. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html#makeClipRevealAnimation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: @EugenPechanec Sure, I'm no stranger to animations.. I just thought that maybe there's a standard api for this particular animation since so many apps had it once I updated to Android P. Maybe my question should have conveyed that better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

1.Add it yo anim folder

**bottom_up.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="90%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**bottom_down.xml :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromYDelta="5"
        android:toYDelta="90%" />
</set>
```

**nothing.xml :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

**Sart a XActivity**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, XActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bottom_up, R.anim.nothing);
```

**Now on finish of XActivity**

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing, R.anim.bottom_down);
}
```

Comment: It's not the same animation, if you slow it down, you see that the content is clipped from 0% to 100% and it only translates the content from 90% to 100% at the end of the animation

Comment: This is so ugly
Not a activity transition